# Python load list from file and print random selection

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file called `projects.txt` that contains the following line of code:

```
['Apollo', 'Astro', 'Aurora', 'Barcelona']
```

I use the following Python2 code to load the file and try to print a random selection but I'm always getting just a single character from my list:

```
import random

projNames = open('projects.txt').read()
print(random.choice(projNames))
```

**Example Result:** a

---

However, if I copy the contents of the text file directly into the code, it works properly for me.

```
import random

projNames = ['Apollo', 'Astro', 'Aurora', 'Barcelona']
print(random.choice(projNames))
```

**Example Result:** Apollo

I need it to be able to load the contents of the file directly rather than editing the code in my `.py` file.

What did I overlook in my original code? I am specifically using Python 2.7.x *(latest version)*.

Comment: Your `projects.txt` file contains one string with content "['Apollo', 'Astro', 'Aurora', 'Barcelona']"?

Comment: Try converting it to a list first, by `projNames = eval(projNames)`

Comment: No, the project file doesn't have the double quotes surrounding the whole list.

Comment: Added the double-quotes to the projects file around the list, and it still didn't work. :(

Comment: @ayhan I added `projNames = eval(projNames)` between file load and print statement and still only prints a single character from the list.

Comment: It may be because you added the double-quotes. It works fine for me.

Comment: @ayhan I removed them after adding them. I went back to the original setup without double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json.loads` after replacing single quote char with a double quote one. The code will be like this:

```
import random
import json

line = open('projects.txt').read().replace("'", '"')  # Format JSON
projNames = json.loads(line) # Load list
print(random.choice(projNames))
```

Comment: Impressive! Could you just elaborate a little or point me to why it would be safer than using the `ast` module?

Comment: @DanijelJ, Oh, I just read that `ast.literal_eval` makes all necessary security checks so it's safe to use it. However, personally I don't like and trust eval-like functions calls and I try to avoid them if it is possible.

Comment: Also, building AST tree is a costly operation. I have checked and JSON solution is three times faster than AST one

Comment: @max What about strings like `['This is valid "Python" literal', 'some other string']`?

Comment: It could be done with one extra replace but I believe that there are situations where `ast` would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse\eval string first to make it Python list:

```
import ast
import random

projNames = ast.literal_eval(open('projects.txt').read())
print(random.choice(projNames))
```

Comment: This is simple, and works perfectly. Thank you. I'm reading through `pydoc ast` to get a better overview.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `read` method will read your file as one big string instead of a `list`. You will need to parse the output of the `read` command (`split` by commas could work for you):

```
>>> my_string.split()
['Apollo', 'Astro', 'Aurora', 'Barcelona']
```